# Token not retrieved for HttpGet

Tags: c#, rest, get, httpclient

I have a REST-Server as well as a REST-client. I am tryping to get a file from the REST-Server. The code in the client is this:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FileResponse> GetThingAsync(string token, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/GetThing/{token}");
        urlBuilder_.Replace("{token}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(token, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        var client_ = _httpClient;
        try
        {
            using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream"));

                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

                var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
               ...
```

The code in the server is this:

```
 [HttpGet("GetThing/{token}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetThing(string thingId)
    {            
        string tokens = thingId;  //line is reached but the 'thingId' is always empty!
```

Why is the 'thingId' not coming up in the server? Do I have to pass it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug: In the server, the name of the parameter must be the same as in the line above. So renaming 'thingId' to 'token' was the solution.